# independ Delphi Application - run without Windows os

Tags: windows, delphi

every one.

I write a windows application by Delphi. And I know if I Replace it with `explorer.exe` the windows will started by my application only.

I want to know how can I make an application with Delphi to be independent of Windows OS and run standalone?

Comment: `explorer.exe` is just the Shell app that the user interacts with.  It is not the actual operating system itself.  If you replace `explorer.exe` with your app, you are simply replacing the top-level piece that the user sees.  Windows itself is still running underneath your app.

Comment: Yes, and I want to know how can I make standalone program or how to restrict windows to start with all needed by my application

Comment: @Reza Those are two entirely different things, either writing your own OS (which is not something you can do with Delphi), or to replace `Explorer.exe` with your own application. Both of those are far too broad for anyone to answer here, there are thousands or even millions of things to know for both tasks, and SO is a one-question-one-answer site.

Comment: You cannot edit your question to ask something completely different. Not only that, SO isn't the place to ask that question. I did ask a similar question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/900309/what-services-can-i-stop-to-keep-system-minimally-running

Comment: thank you Jerry. so I will returned it to first and ask another

Comment: In FreePascal you [`might be able`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Operating_Systems_written_in_FPC) to write your own OS (or fork some of the existing projects).

Comment: Thank you TLama. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Reza You don't want to write an OS. And even if you did, Pascal would be a bad choice.

Comment: Odd closure. It might be a rather simple question, but it's not remotely unclear.

Comment: @David I voted to close as general computing when the question was in that particular state of modification.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how can I make an application with Delphi to be independent of Windows OS and run standalone?

That is not possible. Delphi applications cannot run without an operating system.

Comment: Thank you David . So how can we limit Windows to start with lest services it needed

Comment: That's a quite different question, and one that probably needs a lot more detail, and quite probably isn't even a programming question.

Comment: and would it be possible for you to help me to learn more about it?

Comment: I doubt that I would be able to do that. I'm not a sysadmin.

Comment: @Reza No matter where you post this question, its is too wide.  Why do you want to restrict windows ?  What do you want windows to NOT do ? What are you stopping the users from doing ?  The lower the version of windows, the easier it is to restrict things.  One way is to have an admin login separate from user.  For the user login, delete things from the desktop etc and  restrict the what they can do with registry tweakers.

Comment: @Reza What exactly are you trying to do. If you are interested in changing the Windows apearence and which of some more advanced features are available you could go and make a Shell Replacment like http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpe/ But as Rohit Gupta already mentioed for anything more you woil have to fidle with system registry to disable even more features. And by doing so you can cause Windows to be pretty unstable especially the later versions becouse of deep interdependancies between different features.